# What is my CPU speed?

Tags: linux, performance

I need the CPU speed of my KVM host.

When I am using dmidecode, the result is the following :

> sudo dmidecode  | egrep "Max Speed|Current Speed"
>
> Max Speed: 3100 MHz
>
> Current Speed: 3100 MHz

Whereas, when I am using lscpu,  the result is:

> lscpu | grep "MHz".
>
> CPU MHz:               1600.000

So, why there are two different values, and between the two, which is my actual CPU speed?

Additional :

When the /proc/cpuinfo file has the following result for the speed of the individual cores.

> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000

Can anybody explain in details?

Answer (score 1):

CPU speed is 3100 MHz but it is automatically lowered at 1600 MHz when not on high demand.
This is done by all CPUs today in order to save power/ reduce heat.

So the CPU speed will vary between 1600 and 3100 depending on the CPU load.
If you have something to keep it 90%+ used, it will certainly be at 3100 all the time.

Comment: But one thing I didn't understand, why the "current speed" value in dmidecode is showing 3100 MHz.It should show 1600 Mhz, right?

Comment: One is the actual read speed (or min value from ROM), the other is read form a permanent ROM as max value. They are the min and max values the speed will vary between. If you want the real speed, get an equivalent of CPU-ID for linux, like CPU-G. A list of tools can be found here: http://alternativeto.net/software/cpu-z/?platform=linux